# How to export subtitles and featured videos - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, export, wordpress-featured-image

Is there a way to export subtitles and featured video from a Worpdress website to another?

I found plenty of ways to export posts, pages, media, comments, categories, featured images etc. but all fail in exporting subtitles and featured videos.

Featured videos are only available for video post format
[image: featured video meta]

while subtitles can be added for all posts.
[image: subtitles meta]

I'm switching to "Examiner" theme by StepFox from "Newsbox" theme, also by StepFox. I asked them for assistance but they said there's nothing to do.

I can't even find where they are "stored" in the database.

This is the postmeta table:
[image: postmeta table]

Comment: Is this a custom post type or?

Comment: Subtitles are enabled for every post type. Featured videos just for the video posts.

Comment: Are you working on a certain theme? Can you edit your question and make it more clear?

Comment: Yes. The new theme is "Examiner" by StepFox and the old one is "Newsbox", also by StepFox.
I asked them for assistance but they said there's nothing to do.

Comment: As I've said, please add more info to your question. Is this a custom post type? Are subtitles in a meta field? This is too specific question with no information. Did you try asking theme author for help. They should have a dedicated support.

Comment: look in the post meta table and list the field names where the video and the subtitle....it will be impossible to solve otherwise.

Comment: This is all I have in the postmeta table:
http://i.imgur.com/0SbcjPo.jpg

Comment: id say thats the first page of a lot of pages in your table. Look it if you cant find the information belonging to a certain post to example or understand that you need to create a custom template and know how to post information like the template in use and fields, you might be better to hire someone, something like this could be done cheap if they have access to your server, otherwise they will spend as much time getting information from you as actually coding....

Comment: in order to get the name of the custom field from front end, you can inspect it via chrome by right clicking on the text field and choosing inspect element. Then you should look for the name attribute of the text field. What you see there is what is used as the key in postmeta table

Comment: Tip to find stuff in the database: add some really weird and unique text (like `YellowPotatos2016` and do a global search in PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

This should be in the post's metadata you can extract it with [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

for example:

```
$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );
echo $meta['video'][0];
//use print_r($meta); to pinpoint the value
```